# Pi as AP is not handing out IPs via DHCP

Tags: networking, pi-4, dhcp, access-point, kali

I am running Kali on Pi 4B (their 32bit Pi distribution, v2023.3), attempting to set up the device to function as an Access Point. However I am running into a problem.

I have attempted to follow the following guides:
https://raspberrypi-guide.github.io/networking/create-wireless-access-point
https://yuta-san.medium.com/wifi-access-point-on-kali-linux-with-raspberry-pi-9cfe7408ea1e
https://www.kali.org/blog/remotely-accessing-secure-kali-raspberry-pi/#access-point-mode
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Wireless_AP_with_udhcpd_and_NAT

I continue to run into the same issue. **I am able to see the new network and authenticate to it, however the Pi never leases an IP to my client device.** I can't figure out why. I have ensured the services `NetworkManager` and `wpa_supplicant` are both stopped and disabled to try and avoid conflicts. I have tried using both `hostapd` + `dnsmasq` and `hostapd` + `udhcp` *(never with both dhcp services running at once)* and my IP leasing issue occurs in both scenarios. I have attempted connecting to the Pi AP with both a linux laptop and an android phone.

My question is, what might be stopping the DHCP IP from being leased to my client devices? How can I get my Pi to function as an AP? I want to be able to connect to this network, and SSH into my Pi. I am not worried about packet forwarding or internet connectivity right now.

My current configuration files:

##### hostapd

```
$ cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
interface=wlan0
ssid=mySSID
hw_mode=g
channel=9
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=***
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

##### dnsmasq

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf
interface=wlan0
dhcp-option=option:netmask,255.255.255.0
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.99.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.99.1
log-queries
log-dhcp
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
```

##### udhcp

```
$ cat /etc/udhcpd.conf
start           192.168.99.2
end             192.168.99.254
interface       wlan0
opt     dns     8.8.8.8
option  subnet  255.255.255.0
opt     router  192.168.99.1
option  lease   864000
```

##### interfaces file

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.99.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.99.0
  broadcast 192.168.99.255
  hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

##### dhcpdc

This file did not exist originally, and `apt` shows the package as not installed. Pretty sure this does nothing but was running out of ideas so decided to try anyway.

```
$ cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf
denyinterfaces wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

*sigh*. This took me way too long to troubleshoot, but I finally figured it out.

Turns out by default, dnsmasq does not look in the folder `/etc/dnsmasq.d/` for configurations. There is a line at the bottom of `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` that you have to uncomment in order to configure dnsmasq to read from that folder.

In `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` I now have this

```
# Include all files in a directory which end in .conf
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d/,*.conf
```

I then changed my `/etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq.conf` file to read as follows

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.99.2,192.168.99.50,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.99.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.99.1

log-queries
log-dhcp
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
```

Everything is working like a charm now. No idea why udhcp was not working but I no longer need it. Maybe it was something similar or completely different.